# what is the equivalent of this code in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, translate

I am trying to read some code which is written in ruby. I am conversant with JavaScript and would like to understand what the code translates to in javascript.

Here is the code:

```
def two_d_translate(arr)
   new_arr = []

   arr.each do |subArray|
    ele = subArray[0]
    num = subArray[1]

    num.times { new_arr << ele }
  end

  return new_arr
end
```

The aim of the code is to translate a two-dimensional array to a one-dimensional array by printing the string as many times as the number beside it which is the second element in each sub-array.

I used this to try to imitate it but I wonder if there is something else which could be better.

```
function two_d_translate(arr) {
  let newArr = '';
  let array = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j += 2) {
      let ele = arr[i][j];
      let num = arr[i][j+1];

      if (num === 0){
       continue;
      }

      array[i] = Array(num).fill(ele);
    }
  }

  newArr = array.toString().split(',');
  return newArr;
}
```

This seems to be cool for this test sample.

```
arr_1 = [
  ['boot', 3],
  ['camp', 2],
  ['program', 0]
]

console.log(two_d_translate(arr_1));
```

It will result in the expected output

```
[ 'boot', 'boot', 'boot', 'camp', 'camp' ]
```

but wouldn't in this case

```
arr_1=[
  ['boot', 3],
  ['camp', 0],
  ['program', 2]
]
```

this would result in an undesirable output which is

```
[ 'boot', 'boot', 'boot', '', 'program', 'program' ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Reduce your array into a single one

With [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) you are able to iterate over the entire array whilst pushing/concatenating the last calculation into the final result. This, in combination with [`Array.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill), allows us to create the correct amount, sometimes 0, of the string. And with [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) we can easily translate this 3D array into a 2D one. Here is an example:

```js
function translateTo2D(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((result, [name, count]) =>
    result.concat(Array(count).fill(name)),
  []);
}

const arr = [['a', 2], ['b', 0], ['c', 1]];
console.log(translateTo2D(arr));
```

Answer (score 2):

If your environment allows spread syntax, you can do something like this

```
const arr_1 = [
  ['boot', 3],
  ['camp', 0],
  ['program', 2]
]

const result = arr_1.reduce((acc, [string, times]) => [...acc, ...Array(times).fill(string)], []);
console.log(result); // [ 'boot', 'boot', 'boot', 'program', 'program' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use `flatMap` to join separate runs together:

```js
let translate = a => a.flatMap(([s, n]) => Array(n).fill(s))

console.log(translate([
    ['boot', 3],
    ['camp', 2],
    ['program', 1]
]))
```

If your target doesn't support `flatMap` yet, the equivalent ES6 idiom is `[].concat(...map)`:

```js
let translate = a => [].concat(...a.map(([s, n]) => Array(n).fill(s)))

console.log(translate([
    ['boot', 3],
    ['camp', 2],
    ['program', 1]
]))
```

As a rule of thumb, you use `map/flatMap` when transforming "many things" to "many things", and `reduce` for "many things" to "one thing".

Comment: @ChrisBrownie55: "ES6" refers to the "...concat" thing.